# WFA taskbar minimize while borderless

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have borderless form window, with custom close/minimize buttons
= I have FormBorderStyle:None

And here is my problem. While using this setting, I cannot minimize my app through an icon in taskbar.

If I switch to, for example FormBorderStyle:Fixed3D, where are original system buttons present, the task bar icon come back to life and can minimize the app.

With restoring the app through taskbar icon, there is no problem.

So, is it possible to minimize the app through taskbar icon while FormBorderStyle:None ?

(using .NET 4.5 in MS Visual Studio 2012, Windows Form Application template)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borderless windows don't have the WS_MINIMIZEBOX window style (because the controlbox is removed when you set `FormBorderStyle` to `None`), so you have to add it yourself by overriding the CreateParams property:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style |= WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should explain this.

Comment: Tank you very much, it is working :) Not necessary, but yes, can you please explain this code a little bit, if you have some spare time? Or maybe, I have seen the same type codes while searching different solutions here ... is there some guide for theese hexa things, on what they are based? (cause even visual studio don't give me any useful tooltip while hovering any part of this code) Tanks a lot :) (I wuould like to give you rep, but it seems I cant, sorry :( ...)

Comment: @Zorak if you mean the WS_MINIMIZEBOX style then you can read about window styles [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and extended window styles  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). if you mean only hex, decimal numbers are from 0-9 (base10) and hex is 0-F (base16). if you want to know more just look it up on google :)

Comment: nono, the first one, what is HEX I know ^_^ but its use in c# in this way is a mystery for me... Again, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Works like a charm, even for Windows Forms application forsure, thanks!